# Как проверить на вызов метода с текущим временем в качестве параметра

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Пишу тест и использую вместо одного класса его мок. Класс имеет метод с параметром Calendar. В качестве параметра в одном из случаев должно передаваться текущее время. Пытаюсь проверить этот вызов:

```
       calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    testClass.testMethode();
    verify(mockClass).setTime(calendar);
```

В переменной calendar устанавливаю текущее время перед началом действий. Но пока прорабатывает метод testMethode timer может перещелкнуться на следющую милисекунду и в результате проверка иногда дает ошибку. Что можно сделать, чтобы тест проходил всегда?

Comment: что делает `testMethode()` ? внутри определяется время что ли?

Comment: а что делает тест, проверяет время за какое `testMethode()` отработал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать свой ArgumentMatcher, который проверит что аргумент метода будет отличаться не более чем на какое-то пороговое значение, например, 10 мс.

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    testClass.testMethod();

    Mockito.verify(mock).setTime(Mockito.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Calendar>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            Calendar c = (Calendar) argument;
            return c.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis() < 10;
        }
    }));
```